# Why does eval() not find the function?

Tags: python, python-3.x, eval, redo

```
def __remove_client(self, parameters):
        try:
            client = self.__client_service.remove_client_by_id(int(parameters[0]))

            FunctionsManager.add_undo_operation([self.__client_service, self.__rental_service],
                                                UndoHandler.delete_client_entry, [client[0], client[1]])
            FunctionsManager.add_redo_operation(eval('self.__add_new_client(client[0].id,client[0].name)'))
```

And this gives me : `'UI' object has no attribute '__add_new_client'`
What should I do? Or is there another way of adding that function to my `repo()` stack without calling the function while I am at it?

Comment: Check out [functools.partial](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functools.html#functools.partial) as a way to bind arguments to a function. It returns a new function that can be called later

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to the docs on [Private](https://docs.python.org/3.8/tutorial/classes.html#tut-private) methods:

> Notice that code passed to `exec()` or `eval()` does not consider the classname of the invoking class to be the current class; this is similar to the effect of the global statement, the effect of which is likewise restricted to code that is byte-compiled together. The same restriction applies to `getattr()`, `setattr()` and `delattr()`, as well as when referencing `__dict__` directly.

As for why your `eval()` is pointless, this:

```
eval('self.__add_new_client(client[0].id,client[0].name)')
```

is exacty equivalent to if you just ran the code:

```
self.__add_new_client(client[0].id,client[0].name)
```

directly.  It seems like maybe you were hoping for some kind of delayed lazy evaluation or something but that's not how it works.  Perhaps you wanted to pass a partial evaluation of that method such as:

```
from functools import partial
FunctionsManager.add_redo_operation(partial(self.__add_new_client, client[0].id, client[0].name))
```

If this is your own code, you shouldn't actually use the `__` methods unless you know exactly what you're doing.  There is generally no good reason to use this (Guido has even I think regretted the feature in the past).  It's mostly just useful in the special case described in the docs, where you might intend a subclass to override a special method, and you want to keep a "private" copy of that method that cannot be overridden.

Otherwise just use the single `_` convention for internal attributes and methods.

Comment: Also, as a good rule of thumb, for everyday Python code there's almost no good reason to use `eval()` for anything.  I've only ever used it in some very special, narrow cases.  So if you find yourself reaching for `eval()`, stop, and consider there is probably another way (even if you have to do some research).